# EXCEL: Replacing multiple values in different written formats to include leading zeros following a dash

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a very non-uniform excel spreadsheet containing dozens of test case ID's in different formats that need to have leading zero's added to them.  There are 4 columns of mixed data.  Sometimes the test case ID's appear more than once in the same cell.  I'm looking to simplify changing about 4k instances of these ID's to an 'XYZ-0123' format without disrupting any of the data around it.

Some examples of cell data format includes:

- RQ-0121 is made obsolete and replaced by RZQ-43, RZQ-44, RZQ-45
- NA-33 is made obsolete and replaced by NA-65. NA-33 content is moved down to an SZQ level, replacing content of SZQ 37 (XD-25), XD-25 content becomes a new REQ.
- RX-3 (RQ-11)

Numbers to be converted to 4 digit numbers with leading zeros.  i.e. 'RZ-3' becomes 'RZ-0003', (RQ-11) becomes '(RQ-0011)', 'SQE-542 becomes SQE-0542'.

I've yet to come close with any of my limited excel knowledge.  Find and Replace does not seem powerful enough to select a variable number of numbers after the '-' and then insert the leading zero.

Pic of example data cells:

[image: pic of example data cells:]

Comment: It may help if you can add a screenshot of your data.

Answer (score 2):

```
=LET(a,TEXTSPLIT(A1,SEQUENCE(10,,0),,1),
     b,TEXTSPLIT(A1,a,,1),
CONCAT(TOCOL(VSTACK(a,TEXT(b,"0000")),2,1)))
```

`a` first splits the string by any number(s).
`b` splits the string by the non-number remainders (`a`).
We than stack these and format the numerical strings to format `0000`.
`TOCOL` removes error value (in case the number of splitted values of `a` and `b` don't match). And these are then joined using `CONCAT`.

Comment: At first attempt, this feels like a solution.  I'm still testing it against some of the uglier looking cells.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This gets me 95% of the way there.  If a cell has the data "n/a" it gives me a 'calc' error, which is not common.  I also have to manually move a few comments over to the new cell.  Great stuff otherwise, given the information I had offered you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Not sure if I understood correctly, but does this fix it? `=IF(ISNA(A1),A1,LET(a,TEXTSPLIT(A1,SEQUENCE(10,,0),,1),
     b,TEXTSPLIT(A1,a,,1),
CONCAT(TOCOL(VSTACK(a,TEXT(--b,"0000")),2,1))))`

Comment: When I drag the corner of the cell down to cover each of the 400+ cells in a column, it works on about 98% of them.  I believe the original solve you posted worked just as effectively.  If a cell is empty, it translates to '#VALUE!', and if the cell has the data n/a, it returns '#CALC!'  Your solve still fixed 98% of my translations though, which is very helpful.

Comment: `=IF(OR(ISNA(A1),A1=""),A1,LET(...))` not sure what you expect it to return in case of NA(). Maybe replace the second `A1` with `""`

Comment: Third of course 

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if applicable:

[image]

Formula in `A6`:

```
=PY(
    xl("A1:B3").replace(r'\b(\d+)\b',r'000\1',regex=True).replace(r'\b0+(\d{4})',r'\1',regex=True).fillna('')
)
```

**Note**: You open the python-interpreter first using `=PY(`, then only past the actual python code before confirming through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I like this idea because I want to explore python, but I dont know if I'm able to turn my enterprise version of Office365 to allow the Python beta features.  The python button and "=PY(" string does not appear to work in my current version.

Answer (score -1):

***Extract Test Case ID:*** Use the formula

```
=IFERROR(TEXT(--MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),"0000"),"")
```

…to extract and pad the Test Case ID with leading zeros.

***Recombine Data:*** Use the formula:

```
=IF(B1<>"","XYZ-" & B1,A1)
```

…to recombine the data into the desired format "XYZ-0123".

Apply these formulas to your data, and you should be able to modify the test case IDs without disrupting the rest of the data.

Comment: Would this only return the data as 'XYZ-01234' format?  I should elaborate.  The ouput format should be the same as the input, so 'RQ-1' would be returned as 'RQ-0001' and if the cell data contained different letters, they would also be preserved.  I used XYZ as an example of a variable, but I do not want the output to always be XYZ.